# Webpack is unable to resolve import for ESM module

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, es6-modules

I'm trying to use ESM with typescript and webpack in an nx monorepo. After some configuration, I'm able to transpile to ESM with tsc. For this, I had to add a ".js" to the relative imports.

```
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module.js';
```

Now that I'm trying to use webpack, it doesn't seem to detect that it's a ESM. Here's the error that I'm getting:

```
ERROR in ./apps/nxnest/src/main.ts 9:0-48
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app/app.module.js' in '/home/gabriel/tmp/nxnest/apps/nxnest/src'
resolve './app/app.module.js' in '/home/.../tmp/nxnest/apps/nxnest/src'
  using description file: /home/.../tmp/nxnest/package.json (relative path: ./apps/nxnest/src)
    using description file: /home/.../tmp/nxnest/package.json (relative path: ./apps/nxnest/src/app/app.module.js)
      no extension
        /home/.../tmp/nxnest/apps/nxnest/src/app/app.module.js doesn't exist
      .ts
        /home/.../tmp/nxnest/apps/nxnest/src/app/app.module.js.ts doesn't exist
      .tsx
        /home/.../tmp/nxnest/apps/nxnest/src/app/app.module.js.tsx doesn't exist
      .mjs
        /home/.../tmp/nxnest/apps/nxnest/src/app/app.module.js.mjs doesn't exist
      .js
        /home/.../tmp/nxnest/apps/nxnest/src/app/app.module.js.js doesn't exist
      .jsx
        /home/.../tmp/nxnest/apps/nxnest/src/app/app.module.js.jsx doesn't exist
      as directory
        /home/.../tmp/nxnest/apps/nxnest/src/app/app.module.js doesn't exist

webpack 5.75.0 compiled with 1 error in 1968 ms
```

Because I've to specify ".js" in the import, webpack try to look for it, but I'm using typescript so the file doesn't exists.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Did you update package.json to `type: module`?